# How to change style set for multiple Word files quickly?

Tags: ms-word, styles

Using the style set we can quickly set style(**s**) for ONE .docx Ms Word file.

I have tens of such files need to be set to new style. How can I do that quickly without having to open each file manually?

[image]

[image]

[image]